# Discord.py : coroutine was never awaited

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, discord.py

Can't seem to fix this code where I'm trying to get the name of the discord server from it's invite link.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

async def get_invite_name(link):
    name = await client.fetch_invite(link).guild.name
    return name

print(get_invite_name('https://discord.com/invite/veefriends'))
```

Tried putting `await` infront of `client.fetch_invite(link).guild.name` but it didn't work. I don't understand async.

Tried what @matthew-barlowe suggested but it spit out more errors -

```py
  File "~/DLG/sandbox.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(asyncio.run(get_invite_name('https://discord.com/invite/veefriends')))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "~/DLG/sandbox.py", line 12, in get_invite_name
    return await invite.guild.name
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'guild'
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Client.fetch_invite' was never awaited
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to await the async wrapper function `get_invite_name` as well. Running it in `asyncio.run(get_invite_name('https://discord.com/invite/veefriends'))` will handle that in a non async setting. You will need to import `asyncio` as well.

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

async def get_invite_name(link):
    response = await client.fetch_invite(link)
    name = response.guild.name
    return name

print(asyncio.run(get_invite_name('https://discord.com/invite/veefriends')))
```

If you were calling it in another `async` function then just `await get_invite_name('https://discord.com/invite/veefriends')` would be sufficient

Comment: Tried it, but -

`  File "~/DLG/sandbox.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(asyncio.run(get_invite_name('https://discord.com/invite/veefriends')))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "~/DLG/sandbox.py", line 12, in get_invite_name
    return await invite.guild.name
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'guild'
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Client.fetch_invite' was never awaited`

Comment: @PranavAmmini I can't help you unless you update the question with the error you are getting and the changes you've made to the code

Comment: @PranavAmmini the answer is in your error `in get_invite_name return await invite.guild.name AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'guild'` until you `await` the `client.fetch_invite(link)` its just a coroutine with out the `guild` attribute. you need to save the results of await and then access the `guild` method. I've updated the answer to reflect that.